# How to compare two signatures using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, image, signaturepad

I'm implementing a multi-factor authentication application in Laravel. I store users signatures when the initially get registered to the system. Whenever they try to log in again, I'm asking to draw their signature again and need to verify their signature with the stored signature. Is there any way to do this process. Please anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried about it? Have you looked up on the internet about any libraries existing for the purpose?

Comment: I tried a tool called ImageCompare [link](https://packagist.org/packages/vajiral/php-image-compare). but it seems not working properly